# Proving that a plane reaches a certain velocity at least two times during a flight

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I am asked to prove the following:

A plane initiates its departure at 2pm. The distance it will travel is $2500~\text{mi}$. The plane arrives at its destiny at 7:30pm. Prove that, at least two times during the trip, the speed of the plane is exactly $400~\text{mi}/\text{h}$.

The problem is on the Mean Value Theorem section of the Calculus book but do we really have to use it (or use Rolle's Theorem) to prove that?

Can we just state that the function is continuous and that $400~\text{mi}/\text{h}$ is less than the average speed?

Best Regards.

Comment: That's not quite all of it. The plane might for example just maintain a higher speed forever. And, say, have passenger use a parachute at the destinatiion while the plane keeps flying at 405 knots. I don't think that's recommended, but you should really include **everything** that you need to apply the MVT :-)

Comment: It is important information that the velocity is 0 at the beginning and the end.  It is the mean value theorem that says that the plane must fly at least as fast as its average speed for some portion of the flight.  And the intermediate value theorem that says that if the function is continuous, it passes through 400 on the way to and from cruise.

Comment: Hahah ok but let's be realistic here. Would you use/prove by the MVT?

Comment: You have already done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point time in the journey, the plane must fly at least as fast as its average speed (MVT).

The average speed = 455 mi/h.

The initial speed and final speeds are 0.

Between takeoff and cruise the speed of the plane = 400 mi/h at some time (IVT).

Between cruise and landing the speed of the plane = 400 mi/h at some time (IVT).

if you what to get mathy about it you can say:

$\exists c\in(2:00,7:30)$ such that $v(c) = \frac {dx}{dt}(c) = \frac{x(7:30) - x(2:00)}{5.5}=455$

$t\in [2:00, c], v(t)$ passes through every value in $[0, 455]$

$t\in [c,7:30], v(t)$ passes through every value in $[0, 455]$

But is isn't entirely necessary.